# parsing dates and times

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to tokenize strings like `month/year/day T hour:minute` to `['month', '/', 'year', '/', 'day', ' T ', 'hour', ':', 'minute']`, but have no luck with the regex I am trying. Could anyone please shed some light on this and let me know what's wrong?

```
>>> _tokenize_regex = 'year|month|day|hour|minute|second|.+'
>>> re.findall(_tokenize_regex, 'month/year/day T hour:minute')
['month', '/year/day T hour:minute']
```

The last option `.+` finds the 2nd `findall`-result item, but I would have thought these options are ranked, so that `.+` only matches if none of the others do...

More examples:

```
'month.year somestring' -> ['month', '.', 'year', ' somestring']
'year-month-day hour:minute.second' -> ['year', '-', 'month', '-', 'day', ' ', 'hour', ':', 'minute', '.', 'second']
```

Comment: Consider [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for all your datetime parsing needs.

Comment: @msw: The format is given as the above grammar, not in the format `datetime.strptime` requires.

Comment: You do not provide a possibility for the `/` to match, so everything is eaten up by the `.+` at the end. As it is greedy by default, this is why after `month` everything is in just one group, see [here for a demonstration.](https://regex101.com/r/vG4hA6/1)

Comment: But what about `.+`? Wouldn't that "eat" `/`? (nice site, btw.)

Comment: @orange: It does and this is exactly the problem. At `/`, the engine does not find an appropriate alternative and thus takes `.+`. This expression is greedy by default and takes **the rest of string** (remember, the `.` matches any character except newlines, so there is no need to look for an alternative here). Solution: provide something for the backslash that only matches these (e.g. `[/]`) or use `str.split()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `\w+` to match words, and `[^\w\s]+` to match non-word, non-space characters?

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|[^\w\s]+', 'month/year/day T hour:minute')
['month', '/', 'year', '/', 'day', 'T', 'hour', ':', 'minute']
```

---

`/` matches none of `year`, `month`, ... `second`, but matches `.`. `.+` matches up to the end of the string.

**UPDATE**

alternative approach using `re.split` with captured group to preserve separtors:

```
list(filter(None,
    re.split(r'(month|year|day|hour|minute|second|[^\w\s]+)', text)
))
```

exmaple:

```
>>> import re 
>>> def tokenize(text):
...     tokens = re.split(r'(month|year|day|hour|minute|second|[^\w\s]+)', text)
...     return list(filter(None, tokens))
... 
>>> tokenize('month/year/day T hour:minute') 
['month', '/', 'year', '/', 'day', ' T ', 'hour', ':', 'minute']
>>> tokenize('month.year somestring') 
['month', '.', 'year', ' somestring']
>>> tokenize('year-month-day hour:minute.second') 
['year', '-', 'month', '-', 'day', ' ', 'hour', ':', 'minute', '.', 'second']
```

**UPDATE 2**

`re.findall` with [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
re.findall(
    r'[^\w\s]+|\s+(?!(?:month|year|day|hour|minute|second))\w*\s*|\s+|\w+',
    text
)
```

Comment: I'd expect `' T '` to be returned as 6nd item (1-based counting), but your result returns `'T'` without the spaces. Unfortunately, your approach wouldn't work if you have arbitrary words (not year, month...) in the string that are combined with non-words as they wouldn't be returned as one string.

Comment: @orange, You can use this regular expression, then: `r'\w+|\s+T\s+|[^\w\s]+'` or `r'\w+|\s+[A-Z]\s+|[^\w\s]+'`

Comment: @orange, Could you present another example with expected result? I will come up with different approach according to the example. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I've added some more test cases.

Comment: @orange, I updated the answer with different approach. Please check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your regular expression is the `.+`. In particular, after `month` is matched, the remaining string is matched against `year|month|day|hour|minute|second|.+`. The only expression that matches the remaining string is `.+`. But since this is greedy, it matches the rest of the string.

Based on what I think you're trying to do, you should swap the `.` out for `[/ T:]`.

Also, if you're actually trying to match timestamp strings, you should consider using `strptime`.

Comment: I missed the comment below your code. Since you already noticed that it's the `.+` that's the problem, I'll put the emphasis on the greedy part. You could change this to `.+?` to make it not greedy, but then it would only ever match a single character at a time, so that also doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. `.+?` is the closest to the desired outcome so far.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is best done in one line with a messy regex in python. You could try doing this in steps

```
>>> s = 'month/year/day T hour:minute'
>>> date,t,time = s.partition(' T ')
>>> month, year, day = date.split('/')
>>> hours, minutes = time.split(':')
>>> month, year, day, hours, minutes
('month', 'year', 'day', 'hour', 'minute')
```

For consistency with your expected output you can define separators and use those instead of strings in the partition and split functions.

```
dateSeparator = '/'
timeSeparator = ':'
tSeperator = ' T '
```

Variable names are nicer to work with than list indices and *self-documenting* for the next person who looks at your code. You can always form the list yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with real dates you may need to check whether it is a real date o just a combination of digits. I can recommend use special `datetime` module which can parse dates and check them. Like this:

```
    >>> import datetime
    >>> s='16/2016/03 T 23:52'
    >>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%Y/%m T %H:%M')
    >>> type(d)
    <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    >>> print(d)
    2016-03-16 23:52:00
```

Here you get special datetime object which is very comfortable for operations with dates. More info and examples are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior